# Java Socket (TCP) Client Callback Functions

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am writing a simple Java Socket Client that is able to connect to a socket and pass a certain request to the server. Pretty much what I am trying to do:

1. Java Client connects to socket sends request to server
2. Server processes request and sends back "starting"
3. Java Client waits for next progress update
4. Server sends "progress 10%"
5. Java Client receives the progress update and processes accordingly
6. Server sends progress update 20%... so on so forth

I do not want to constantly check if there is something in the input stream but rather have the client retrieve the data as soon as there is something pending and process it (on a background thread). I am fairly new to working with java and networking in general so I don't know much about implementing this.

**Server code (python, running on a raspberry pi):**

```
import SocketServer
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn, StreamRequestHandler
import sys
import time
import socket

# We mix with ThreadingMixIn to allow several simultaneous
# clients. Otherwise, a slow client may block everyone.
class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
     pass

# StreamRequestHandler provides us with the rfile and wfile attributes
class RequestHandler(StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print str(self.client_address) + 'connected'
        data = "foo"
        while data != "":
            data = self.rfile.readline()
            print data
            try:
                self.wfile.write("foo\n")
            except socket.error: # Client went away, do not take that data into account
                data = ""
        print 'Handler Exiting'
        self.request.close()

    def finish(self):
        print 'Client Disconnected'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PORT = 80

    ThreadingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    server = ThreadingTCPServer(("", PORT), RequestHandler)
    try:    
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nServer Terminated"
```

Basically at the end of prototyping I will be implementing this into an Android app. If you were wondering I am planning on using this to run some home automation and some other things.

This is the current **client code** I am working with (from an example online and I modified it a little):

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientTest {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    private BufferedWriter writer = null;

    public ClientTest(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    }

    public void send(String msg) throws IOException {
        writer.write(msg, 0, msg.length());
        writer.flush();
    }

    public String recv() throws IOException {
        return reader.readLine();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.15");
            ClientTest client = new ClientTest(host, 80);
            //ClientTest client2 = new ClientTest(host, 9999);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
                client.send("bar " + i + "\n");
                String response = client.recv();
                System.out.println("" + i + ": " + response);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //client2.send("Client2\n");
            }


            client.socket.close();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //client2.socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `String response = client.recv();` I want to have this function automatically called whenever the server sends back a request and have the message processed in the background. (I think it is somewhere along the lines of a callback function)

All answers appreciated!

Comment: "I do not want to constantly check if there is something in the input stream": You don't have to. Just have a thread blocked in `read()`. There is no callback architecture in `java.net`. You might want to have a look at `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, but I doubt that you really need it.

Comment: @EJP If you have time, could you please show me a little example code on this way of going about it. I am fairly new to networking and java in general, so could you please tell me what  "thread blocked" is? Thanks!

Comment: Have a good look at the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.